# Calling a view function within a "classic" function in Django

Tags: django, django-views

Is it possible to call a view function (and return a rendered HTML back to the browser) from a function?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view function is just a regular function that takes a `HttpRequest` object and returns a `HttpResponse` object, nothing special. You can call it from any other function. And if you want to then send the `bytes` in the `HttpResponse.content` to a browser, you can of course do that, if you have some sort of open network connection to that browser.

Likely, the real question is if the "classic" function is connected to the receiving browser in any way. Usually via a socket on the server that sends the HTML `bytes` and some header data to an Nginx server that then relays it to the browser. That's what in Django, the `urls.py` and `wsgi.py` abstract away.

Comment: Thank you for these clarifications. I suspected that I would have to, at least, have a connection via a websocket.